# force input form enter uppercase to backend in vue.js

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I've tried to input 'a001', the display will show 'A001' because the CSS rule.
What's the proper/best way to convert it to uppercase before passing to backend?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myid: ''
  },
  methods: {
    click: function() {
      console.log('clicked id=', this.myid)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div input {
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="myid" placeholder="My ID" />
  <button type="button" @click="click">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm wonder is there css rule to simplified the extra code if multiple field required to convert

Comment: The CSS has style="text-transform:uppercase" but it's only visual, if you try to send the data, it will pass as you have typed instead of how you view it as i.e uppercased letters. Javascript is the only way.

Answer (score 17):

Custom directive:

```
Vue.directive("uppercase", {
    update: function (el) {
        el.value = el.value.toUpperCase()
    }
})

<input type="text" v-model="myid" placeholder="My ID" v-uppercase/>
```

Comment: This solution is clean - but it seems to leave the last character lowercase each time when submitted to the database? On the frontend it is all caps. Just me?

Comment: Does this solution take into account highlighting text in the middle of the existing input and pasting characters?

Comment: @Grant I added el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')); after the value update and that seemed to fix the last character issue. Found this solution in a comment here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2804

Comment: I have noticed this does work with the above @TonyRush link.  However, just found it does not play well with Vuelidate.  In turn, even after an `$reset()` it makes it dirty again right away.

Comment: or change the [Hook Function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions) from `update` to `componentUpdated`, which called after the component been updated

Answer (score 11):

The simple way without any `computed` or `$event`

```html
<v-text-field
   v-model="batchNo"
   label="Batch Number"
   @input="(val) => (batchNo = batchNo.toUpperCase())"
   >
</v-text-field>
```

Here a text-field from Vuetify is being used but you can use it with an HTML input as well.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer has problem: the last character is still lower case.

```
<textarea v-model="remark" 
                    @input="remark=$event.target.value.toUpperCase()"></textarea>
```

this works, but it requires to write more code if there are many fields.

maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I get it to work is:

```js
Vue.directive('uppercase', {
  bind(el, _, vnode) {
    el.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
      e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase()
      vnode.componentInstance.$emit('input', e.target.value.toUpperCase())
    })
  },
})
```

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="model"
    v-uppercase
    type="text"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript function called `toUpperCase()` like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myid: ''
  },
  methods: {
    click: function() {
    var str = this.myid.toUpperCase();
      console.log('clicked id=', str)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div input {
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="myid" placeholder="My ID" />
  <button type="button" @click="click">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Now you can remove the css rule if you only want to pass the value capitalized without showing it or either you can keep it.
Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to store the uppercase value, then the two provided answers would work IF you pass the computed value to the server - I think some mau have missed the "before passing it to the backend" part of you question. However if you want to DISPLAY it in the input in uppercase as the user types and update the actual input v-model in parallel (which is what you are probably already passing to the backend), you would need something like:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    form: {
      id:''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    forceUpper (e, obj, prop) {
      const start = e.target.selectionStart
      e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase()
      this.$set(obj, prop, e.target.value)
      e.target.setSelectionRange(start, start)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input
    v-model="form.id"
    @input="forceUpper($event, form, 'id')"
  />
  <br><br>
  {{ form }}
</div>
```

NOTE: If you are using a UI/CSS framework that wraps input elements (such as Quasar), you may need to use the @input.native event instead of @input. @input in those normally just passes the value and not the whole event.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably an old question but somebody maybe here someday looking for help so why not share what works for me. Two things, the first is, you're going to make a custom component that emits an input event but before tying up this event you're going to use Javascript 'toUpperCase()' method on the value that will be emitted.
Second- A custom component also but this time you can watch for the value when it changes then turn the current value to uppercase and bind that value to the internal model changes. Well to save some ink lets dive into some coding...

```js
Vue.component('app-input', {
  props: ['value'],
  template: `<input class="input__field input__first" :value="value" @keyup="keyUpHandler"/>`,
  methods: {
    keyUpHandler($event) {
      this.$emit('input', String($event.target.value).toUpperCase());
    },
  },
});

Vue.component('app-input2', {
  props: ['value'],
  data() {
    return {
      innerValue: '',
    }
  },
  template: `<input class="input__field input__second" v-model="innerValue"/>`,
  watch: {
    // Handles internal model changes.
    innerValue(newVal) {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$emit('input', newVal);      
      });
    },
    // Handles external model changes.
    value(newVal) {
      this.innerValue = String(newVal).toUpperCase();
    },
  },
  created() {
    if (this.value) {
      this.innerValue = String(this.value).toUpperCase();
    }
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    obj: {},
  }
});
```

```css
.input__field {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="input">
    <!-- C U S T O M - C O M P O N E N T - 1 -->
    <app-input v-model="obj.first"/>
  </div>
  <p>FIRST- {{ obj.first }}</p>
  <br/>
  <div class="input">
    <!-- C U S T O M - C O M P O N E N T - 2 -->
    <app-input2 v-model="obj.second"/>
  </div>
  <p>SECOND- {{ obj.second }}</p>
</div>
```

I always prefer the second method but you can play with these two and hopefully it helps you or somebody else.

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
   <input type="text" v-model="message" />
   <h4>{{ message | uppercase }}</h4>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
Vue.filter('uppercase', function (value) {
   return value.toUpperCase()
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'foo'
   }
})
```

I wish this solves your problem.