# How to apply Vue directives to Vuetify custom components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have some vuetify custom components (input components) like this:

```
// Component 
<v-text-field 
  background-color="#ffffff"
  outlined 
  dense
  hide-details
  class="text-field"
  :class="textFieldClass"
  v-model="content"
  :disabled="disabled"
  :rules="textFieldRules"
  @keydown="handleKeydown"
  :maxlength="maxLength"
  :error="textFieldError"
></v-text-field>


//Parent
<v-container>
  <v-row class="d-flex justify-center">
    <v-col cols="4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-center">
        <label class="input-label"> Insert data </label>
      </div>
      <InputTextField v-uppercase :textFieldRules="[rules.inputDataFormat]" :textFieldContent.sync="inputData"></InputTextField>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

I'm trying to use a Vue custom directive called "uppercase" on my components:

```
import Vue from "vue";

export const InputCase = {
  update: function (el) {
    el.value = el.value.toUpperCase();
  }
};

Vue.directive("uppercase", InputCase);
```

But I have found that the vuetify components don't have the value property, so it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the directive to your custom component `InputTextField`, not directly to Vuetify's `v-text-field` so the statement *I have found that the vuetify components don't have the value property* is not correct. **Yours** component doesn't have a `value` property. `v-text-field` [does](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props) as it supports `v-model`

But it does not matter here much. Problem is that Vue directives are pretty low level. From the docs:

> Note that in Vue 2.0, the primary form of code reuse and abstraction is components - however there may be cases where you need some low-level DOM access on plain elements, and this is where custom directives would still be useful.

So directives operates directly on the DOM level, not on component level. `el` passed into directive hooks is not a component instance, it is always DOM element generated when the component is rendered. This is now properly [documented in Vue 3 docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#usage-on-components)

So your directive (taken probably from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54839452/381282)) will not work. One solution can be based on the other answer - [Custom directive v-focus is not working on vuetify component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58135441/381282) - but it makes some assumptions on how the Vuetify component is rendered. Also check [this forum thread](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/inputs-always-in-uppercase-using-v-model/7450/15) for complications and other solutions...

Personally I would not go the directive route and stick to the advise given by Vue authors - **the primary form of code reuse and abstraction is components**

Note: I really don't like the interface of your `InputTextField` custom input. Input handling in Vue is based on `v-model` and other devs (in your team) are used to it. Why make your custom input (essentially a wrapper) different?

You already have a custom component `InputTextField` so it should be easy to add simple boolean prop, for example `uppercase` and use it together with computed based `v-model` implementation like this:

```js
Vue.component('custom-input', {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }, 
    uppercase: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  template: `<input type="text" v-model="model">`,
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() { return this.value },
      set(newVal) {
        this.$emit('input', this.uppercase ? newVal.toUpperCase() : newVal)
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value: {
      // to handle the situation when model value set by parent is not uppercase
      handler: function(newValue) {
        if(this.uppercase && newValue !== newValue.toUpperCase())
          this.model = newValue
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      text: "Hello"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <custom-input v-model="text" :uppercase="true"></custom-input>
  <pre>{{ text }}</pre>
</div>
```

When upgrading to Vue 3 you can get rid of standalone props as `uppercase` and easily rewrite your component to use [custom `v-model` modifiers](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#handling-v-model-modifiers)